# What was Dresden referencing here?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Harry Dresden's 11th book, *Turn Coat* features a massive throwdown

> on 'Demonreach', an island he has claimed as a sanctum

which features a potent group of people:

> The White Council, the White Court, Harry, Billy, and Georgia (backed by the Za Lord's Guard and the Za Lord's Militia, headed by Toot-toot)

fighting against

> the skinwalker, Madeline Raith, and a whole host of summoned baddies.

Every single one of them (excepting Harry's followers) showed up to fight against Harry, to claim

> Morgan

who Harry knew to be innocent.  Harry was using the situation to pit all of them against the baddies, and save a prisoner of theirs.

He tipped this, subtly, to Ebenezer by quoting an old cartoon.  He says, "Wile E. Cyote, Sooooper Genius"

Aside from the obvious character reference, is Harry referencing a specific Wile E. Coyote cartoon?  Ebenezer seems to recognize his quote to mean more than, "I have a plan that is likely to fail spectacularly, causing me grievous bodily harm."

Comment: That's not Changes, it's the one right before it, Turn Coat.

Comment: Yeah "Changes" involves a trip to Mexico. And other, darker, venues. Muhahahahha

Comment: D'Oh!  I'm looking forward to the next book (on my 2nd read-through of the series).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Looney Tunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looney_Tunes) short in question is "[Operation: Rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation%3a_Rabbit)", which featured Wile E. Coyote pitted against Bugs Bunny instead of his more familiar foil, the Road Runner.  It is the first of five cartoons featuring the duo.

In the short, Wile E. Coyote speaks, which is also different from his appearances versus the Road Runner.  He introduces himself to Bugs as "Wile E. Coyote, Genius", and then later gloats to himself about being a super-genius as his particularly dastardly plan is about to turn on him (once again, of course).

[The cartoon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoKA2OLJ8hs) can be found on YouTube; the introduction can be heard at the 0:59 mark, super-genius at 6:24.

Comment: This is certainly the source of the quotation, and I have to agree, after watching, that there's no real connection to his plan.